# How to select elements with second data attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this HTML

```
<td data-id="1 2 3"></td>
<td data-id="1 2 3"></td>
<td data-id="1 1 3"></td>
<td data-id="3 3 3"></td>
```

And I want to select only the elements with SECOND data id equal to 2.

How to write that selector ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24330042/2324107) is good for this specific case, but if you want a more generic one, you can use filter :

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('id').match(/^\d+ 2 /);
})
```

Comment: How to do that with 2 being a variable?

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
$('td[data-id*=" 2 "]')
```

It suppose to match only " 2 "